# how to install postfix as simple as possible?

Tags: ubuntu, email, php, smtp, postfix

I'm not even sure whether **postfix** is what I need. I need to be able to execute mail() function inside php scripts to test my sites.
I don't need it to be secure or whatever. I'm the only person who will be using it.

What do I need to do (and how) to deploy this?

I have online mail servers available to which I can connect using SMTP. I just need to configure whatever I need to configure in my pc for mails to be sent.

My OS is ubuntu 10.10 64bit.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to install Postfix:

> sudo apt-get install postfix

It should work right away.